# Remove Flip image in Mobile Screen

Tags: html, css

I have try to flip the Image. That's working fine. But this Image Flipping is happened in Mobile screen also. I don't want this Flipping in Mobile Screen. I have tried a method. But that is not Working.

Here is the Code...!

```css
.f1_container {
    position: relative;
    margin:10px;
    width: 450px;
    height: 281px;
    z-index : 1;
    float:left;
}
.f1_container {
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;
}
.f1_card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.0s linear;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 1.0s linear;
}
.f1_container:hover .f1_card {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #aaa;
}
.face {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.face.back {
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #aaa;
}
body{width:2000px}

@media (max-width: 482px) {
  .f1_container:hover .f1_card {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #aaa;
}
  }
```

```html
<div class="f1_container">
    <div class="shadow f1_card">
        <div class="front face">
            <img src="http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/03/48/0b/14/dolphin-view-chalets.jpg" style="height: 281px; width: 450px;" />
        </div>
        <div class="back face center">Some text inside here</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="f1_container">
    <div class="shadow f1_card">
        <div class="front face">
            <img src="http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/03/48/0b/14/dolphin-view-chalets.jpg" style="height: 281px; width: 450px;" />
        </div>
        <div class="back face center">Some text inside here</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="f1_container">
    <div class="shadow f1_card">
        <div class="front face">
            <img src="http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/03/48/0b/14/dolphin-view-chalets.jpg" style="height: 281px; width: 450px;" />
        </div>
        <div class="back face center">Some text inside here</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="f1_container">
    <div class="shadow f1_card">
        <div class="front face">
            <img src="http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/03/48/0b/14/dolphin-view-chalets.jpg" style="height: 281px; width: 450px;" />
        </div>
        <div class="back face center">Some text inside here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to hide this Flipping in Mobile Screen View.

Comment: You should rather do this the other way around ... _add_ the flip effect only inside a media query for “large enough” screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add you hover event to a media query with a `min-width` instead, to only allow it to work on viewports larger than that.

```
@media (min-width: 482px) {
    .f1_container:hover .f1_card {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #aaa;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
.f1_container:hover .f1_card {
  transform: none;
}
```

change  CSS property with above